# How does XmlItemExporter Works (in scrapy)?

Tags: python, scrapy

Does it save items to XML file  in the same order it scrapes them?

What is the order for adding items to xml file?

the first in - at the bottom or the first in - at the top of xml file?

I cant get the needed order - it's like

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

:(   (i assumed it saved items to XML file in the same order it scraped them..)

Comment: How do you know what the scraped order is, and is it consistent? I ask because scrapy does not guarantee crawl order.

Comment: As @Talvalin noted, it depends on the order of spider crawling - and there is no guaranteed order, actually. But, there were several discussions on how to order crawled items: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566322/scrapy-crawl-urls-in-order) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379065/order-of-crawling-in-scrapy). Hope that helps.