# Force scrapy to crawl link in order they appear

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a spider with scrapy to crawl a website, the index page is a list of link like
www.link1.com, www.link2.com, www.link3.com
and that site is updated really often, so my crawler is part of a process that runs everey hours, but I would like to crawl only the new link that i havent crawled yet.
my problem is that scrapy randomise the way it treats each link when going deep.
is it possible to force sracpy to crawl in order ? Like 1 then 2 and then 3, so that I can save the last link that i've crawled and when starting the process again just compare link 1 with formerly link 1 ?

Hope this is understandable, sorry for my poor english,

kindly response,

thanks

EDIT :

```
class SymantecSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'symantecSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['symantec.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/vulnerabilities.jsp'
        ]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="mrgnMD"]/following-sibling::table')), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        open("test.t", "ab").write(response.url + "\n")
```

Comment: Why don't you just save the links that you scrape somewhere, then check them later to make sure you don't scrape the same site twice?

Comment: Hm, because the list of link i crawl is pretty long and my bot is meant to be running for a long time so i might have to save a very large amount of link and then the comparaison between saved link and new might take a very long time in a few month

Comment: in fact, theres's actually 1400 links on the page, so what i would like to do is crawl them all the first time, but then when my spider is recalled like 1 hour after, just check if theres a new link and crawl it if there is

Comment: One thing you might do is every time you scrape the page, get a hash code of the content (the list of links). Then in an hour, read the content again to get another hash code, and if the hashes are the same, don't scrape at all. Another thing you can do is save all the scraped values in a SQLite database and query that database every time you scrape. This will be faster than you think for only 1400 links. That way, you can also save useful data on the database like when it was scraped so you can re-scrape a link every week for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I'll try that, just to be sure, there,s no way to force scrapy to treat the links in the order they appears on the page ? This would save me a lot of time if i could just do that !

This is my starting url =http://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/vulnerabilities.jsp

and i'd like scrapy to crawl the links below Vulnerabilities and treat them in the order they appears but it seems that my callback_method don't want to do that =)

Comment: Maybe there is, I don't know. I thought I'd share how I would approach the problem. Unfortunately, scrapy is not a very active tag on this site, and that's why you haven't gotten a single answer yet (answers appear below, here we are just posting comments). But hopefully someone will come along and give you a proper answer. I will add the Python tag to your question so you can get some more views (and because this is a Python question).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your time and answers, i will post the answer or the workaround i use for this as soon as i solve the probleme

Comment: I think the links are scraped in order, it's just callbacks are called out of order, because some requests are downloaded faster. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6566322/248296)

Answer (score 3):

Try this example.
Construct a list and append all the links to it.
Then pop them one by one to get your requests in order.

I recommend doing something like @Hassan mention and pipe your contents to a database.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import log


class SymantecSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'symantecSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['symantec.com']
    allLinks = []
    base_url = "http://www.symantec.com"

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request('http://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/vulnerabilities.jsp', callback=self.parseMgr)]

    def parseMgr(self, response):
        # This grabs all the links and append them to allLinks=[]
        self.allLinks.append(HtmlXPathSelector(response).select("//table[@class='defaultTableStyle tableFontMD tableNoBorder']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/@href").extract())
        return Request(self.base_url + self.allLinks[0].pop(0), callback=self.pageParser)

    # Cycle through the allLinks[] in order
    def pageParser(self, response):
        log.msg('response: %s' % response.url, level=log.INFO)
        return Request(self.base_url + self.allLinks[0].pop(0), callback=self.pageParser)
```

Comment: Dont you have to return a `Request` in `parseMgr` for each link?

Comment: good idea (I got it)! `parseMgr` manage only the first link & then it's the `pageParser` that manage the rest.

Comment: Should just add a condition `if not empty list` in the `pageParser` for the last link in the list.

Answer (score 1):

SgmlLinkExtractor will extract links in the same order they appear on the page.

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
links = SgmlLinkExtractor(
    restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="mrgnMD"]/following-sibling::table',
        ).extract_links(response)
```

You can use them in the `rules` in your CrawlSpider:

```
class ThreatSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'threats'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/vulnerabilities.jsp',
    ]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="mrgnMD"]/following-sibling::table')
            callback='parse_threats'))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i've tried your code but it appears that the order of the url is still wrong, did i missed something ? heres the code i'im using :

Comment: I'll edit my question with the code, can't figure how to post code in comment :X