# Understanding callbacks in Scrapy

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

I am new to Python and Scrapy. I have not used callback functions before. However, I do now for the code below. The first request will be executed and the response of that will be sent to the callback function defined as second argument:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                      callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

I am unable to understand following things:

1. How is the `item` populated?
2. Does the `request.meta` line executes before the `response.meta` line in `parse_page2`?
3. Where is the returned `item` from `parse_page2` going?
4. What is the need of the `return request` statement in `parse_page1`? I thought the extracted items need to be returned from here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html):

> For spiders, the scraping cycle goes through something like this:
>
> 1. You start by generating the initial Requests to crawl the first URLs, and specify a callback function to be called with the response
>      downloaded from those requests.
>
>    The first requests to perform are obtained by calling the
>      `start_requests()` method which (by default) generates `Request` for the
>      URLs specified in the `start_urls` and the `parse` method as callback
>      function for the Requests.
> 2. In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return either `Item` objects, `Request` objects, or an iterable of both.
>      Those Requests will also contain a callback (maybe the same) and will
>      then be downloaded by Scrapy and then their response handled by the
>      specified callback.
> 3. In callback functions, you parse the page contents, typically using *Selectors* (but you can also use BeautifulSoup, lxml or whatever
>      mechanism you prefer) and generate items with the parsed data.
> 4. Finally, the items returned from the spider will be typically persisted to a database (in some *Item Pipeline*) or written to a file
>      using *Feed exports*.

Answers:

> How is the `'item'` populated does the `request.meta` line executes before `response.meta` line in `parse_page2`?

Spiders are managed by Scrapy engine. It first makes requests from URLs specified in `start_urls` and passes them to a downloader. When downloading finishes callback specified in the request is called. If the callback returns another request, the same thing is repeated. If the callback returns an `Item`, the item is passed to a pipeline to save the scraped data.

> Where is the returned item from `parse_page2` going?
>
> What is the need of `return request` statement in `parse_page1`? I thought the extracted items need to be returned from here ?

As stated in the docs, each callback (both `parse_page1` and `parse_page2`) can return either a `Request` or an `Item` (or an iterable of them). `parse_page1` returns a `Request` not the `Item`, because additional info needs to be scraped from additional URL. Second callback `parse_page2` returns an item, because all the info is scraped and ready to be passed to a pipeline.

Comment: I have read this part already...however I was confused by how the control is flowing in the code that I have mentioned..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... Now it makes sense when i read the complete thing again

Comment: Ok..ill do that...i have some understanding Please correct me if i am wrong - as you said that callback function can return requests which are sent to a queue for processing...so in parse_page1 request object is returned...so it is that at this point (when parse_page1 ends) the callback function parse_page2 is called

Comment: No, `parse_page2` is called when the response for the request is downloaded. This is asynchronous. In the mean time previous request can be finished downloading in `parse_page2` is called for another response.

Comment: Ok...sorry for confusion... i want to say that when parse_page1 ends ..at this point request is performed for the returned request object and when response is downloaded the callback function parse_page2 is called.

Comment: Generally yes. Note: it can happen that the returned request is not sent immediately to the server, but is waiting to be sent, because there is a [scheduler](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#scheduler) which decides when to start downloading the URL (because of download delays specified in settings and other Scrapy parameters)

Comment: It can also happen that you issue two requests, but callback for the last request is called earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566322/scrapy-crawl-urls-in-order

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, scrapy uses [a twisted reactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/reactor-basics.html) to call spider functions, hence using a single loop with a single thread ensures that
2. the spider function caller expects to either get item/s or request/s in return, requests are put in a queue for future processing and items are sent to configured pipelines
3. saving an item (or any other data) in request meta makes sense only if it is needed for further processing upon getting a response, otherwise it is obviously better to simply return it from `parse_page1` and avoid the extra http request call

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation... however I am still confused in the third question...I think I didn't explained it clearly. So, what I want to ask is that where is the request instance in parse_page1 returned to? Why is the return request needed - Is the callback function called when control reaches this statement ? Also, Can I pass a list of items in the same way as done here and return the list from parse_page2 ?

Answer (score 1):

in [scrapy: understanding how do items and requests work between callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589136/scrapy-understanding-how-do-items-and-requests-work-between-callbacks/45852217#45852217)
,eLRuLL's answer is wonderful.

I want to add the part of item transform. First, we shall be clear that callback function only work until the response of this request dwonloaded.

in the code the scrapy.doc given,it don't declare the url and request of page1 and. Let's set the url of page1 as "http://www.example.com.html".

[parse_page1] is the callback of

```
scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com.html",callback=parse_page1)`
```

[parse_page2] is the callback of

```
scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",callback=parse_page2)
```

when the response of page1 is downloaded, parse_page1 is called to generate the request of page2:

```
item['main_url'] = response.url # send "http://www.example.com.html" to item
request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                         callback=self.parse_page2)
request.meta['item'] = item  # store item in request.meta
```

after the response of page2 is downloaded, the parse_page2 is called to retrun a item:

```
item = response.meta['item'] 
#response.meta is equal to request.meta,so here item['main_url'] 
#="http://www.example.com.html".

item['other_url'] = response.url # response.url ="http://www.example.com/some_page.html"

return item #finally,we get the item recording  urls of page1 and page2.
```