# Learning to scrape product details on amazon using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to learn web scraping. so what i'm trying to do is
insert a category link myself ex: https://www.amazon.in/TVs/b/ref=nav_shopall_sbc_tvelec_television?ie=UTF8&node=1389396031

now go to division having class 's-item-container' 
now read the url inside  tag having class 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal' 
open the url get the relevant details
come back
and repeat for other divisions having s-item-container as class

But i don't know how to do it. the video i'm learning from is showing me how to extract from the list page only.
if someone can show me the code i can study that.

Comment: You have to use css selectors to scrape, you should probably do some reading about how to select elements by css selector. For a quick example, in order to select the div with class s-item-container. You can use ".s-item-container" this will select every element in the dom with class s-item-container.

Comment: Here is a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: i can do that but what i cant do is open the product details page and come back to list page after getting the details. i can select divisions with classes and ids

Comment: @UtkarshTomar you have to use callback, check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648475/understanding-callbacks-in-scrapy