# Scraping AJAX content with Scrapy

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a project that involves getting latest reviews from Google play store. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706111/scrapy-crawlspider-for-ajax-content) but not able to solve my problem

Reviews on play store are by default sorted by "helpfulness" but I want to get the latest review.

For ex
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.boombeach

I looked at the chrome->dev tools->network and on selecting "Newest" button this request is made

```
reviewType=0&pageNum=0&id=com.playdead.limbo.full&reviewSortOrder=0&xhr=1
```

I am trying https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?reviewType=0&pageNum=0&id=com.supercell.boombeach&reviewSortOrder=0 
but it always open the default page.

I am using scrapy .