# Chaining requests with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Now I can see that scrapy downloads all pages concurrently, but what I need is to chain `people` and `extract_person` methods, so that when I get list of persons urls in method `people` I follow all of them and scrape all info I need and only after that I continue with another page people urls. How can I do that?

```
def people(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    urls = sel.xpath(XPATHS.URLS).extract()
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(
            url=BASE_URL+url,
            callback=self.extract_person,
        )

def extract_person(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    name = sel.xpath(XPATHS.NAME).extract()[0]
    person = PersonItem(name=name)
    yield student
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the [priority](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) of the requests:

> priority (int) – the priority of this request (defaults to 0). The priority
>   is used by the scheduler to define the order used to process requests.
>   Requests with a higher priority value will execute earlier. Negative
>   values are allowed in order to indicate relatively low-priority.

Setting the priority for person requests to `1` will let Scrapy know to process them first:

```
for url in student_urls:
    yield Request(
        url=BASE_URL+url,
        callback=self.extract_person,
        priority=1
    )
```

Comment: As I can see in logs, it's still pretty much the same. There are still a lot of `people` method executions before `extract_person`.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov yeah, they are already probably on the queue due to how `start_urls` are handled internally. Give a try to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9176662/771848) - override `start_requests()` method and return a list of urls from it. Thanks. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the priority effect how they are processed within the queue. I also could not get priority keyword to work properly in my crawlers.